# Get a random value from a list which is not equal to a particular number?

Tags: python, integer

I have list of numbers:

```
list = [1,2,3]
```

and would like to get a random integer, k, that does not equal to x from the above list

I've tried:

```
x = 2
k = (i for i in array if i !=x)
```

but this returns a generator object instead of an integer. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What does it even mean to "_call a random integer_"? Do you want to produce an integer that is not equal to any number on the list? (_List_, not _array_.) If so, would that number have any other limitations?

Comment: Does "random" mean random as in "a different one every time", or random as in "it doesn't matter which one"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import random

k = random.choice([i for i in array if i != x])
```

Note that the `[]` are required in this case, as:

```
random.choice(i for i in array if i != x)
```

which is equivalent to

```
gen = (i for i in array if i != x)
random.choice(gen)
```

doesn't work since `choice` requires a sequence, which a generator is not.

Comment: Just for clarity, using `()` instead of `[]` will create a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) instead of a [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), which might not be abundantly clear from this (correct) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use square brackets on your list comprehension! Then you can get the first value with [0].

e.g.

```
array = [1,2,3]
x = 2
k = [i for i in array if i !=x][0]
```

Comment: How this will give a random indexed number in the list?